# In Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2, at what level are the perks unlocked in Multiplayer?

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

For example: faster reloading, carrying 2 weapons, unlimited sprinting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [here](http://www.video-game-forums.com/call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2/73325-mw2-perks.html):

PERKS - SLOT ONE

- Marathon - Start
- Sleight of Hand - Start
- Scavenger - Lvl 13
- Bling - Lvl 21
- One Man Army - Lvl 45

PERKS - SLOT TWO

- Stopping Power - Start
- Lightweight - Start
- Hardline - Lvl 9
- Cold-Blooded - Lvl 25
- Danger Close - Lvl 33

PERKS - SLOT THREE

- Commando - Start
- Steady Aim - Start
- Scrambler - Lvl 17
- Ninja - Lvl 29
- SitRep - Lvl 37
- Last Stand - Lvl 41

The link also has the descriptions if you can't tell what each perk does based on its name.

Comment: Also the perks upgrade after a certain amount of usage, for example after running 26 miles you unlock Marathon Pro.